# Why is the integral of a vector field over some volume not given importance?

Tags: integration, vectors, physics, differential-forms

I seldom see integration of vector fields over volumes or surfaces in pure math, but that practice seems to be quite widespread in physics. The integral of the momentum density in a volume $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, for instance, can be written as $$ \mathbf{P} = \int_{\Omega} \rho(\mathbf{r}) \mathbf{u} \mathrm{d} V $$, where  $\mathbf{u}$ is a vector field (velocity field) and $\rho$ a scalar field (mass density). It is pretty clear to me how to perform this integration (componentwise basically), and the result is a vector( $\mathbf{P}$), but I can't seem to remember any maths textbook discussing or defining this type of integration. Is my memory just failing me or is this the case? Is there some problem with the integration of vector fields over volumes that I'm failing to grasp? Is there any reason why it would be uninteresting to mathmaticians?

I can see that perhaps the location of $\mathbf{P}$ is not so well defined (meaning, does it live on a tangent space  $T$ and if so where exactly?) and I can't see 100% how it fits with differential forms and the like, perhaps there are issues with integrating this over more general things than $\mathbb{R}^n$? are these issues important enough that mathmaticians avoid this completely? In short: why is this avoided? (if it is).

Comment: You can definitely integrate vector-valued functions (even in the case of infinite-dimensional vector spaces, I suppose) or vector-valued differential forms (more generally), but you need values in a fixed vector space. These show up mostly, but not entirely, because of physics and allied fields like fluid mechanics. But they do show up (and even in textbooks).

Comment: What do you mean values in a fixed vector space? you mean you can integrate vector-valued forms but not forms that take values in tangwnt spaces to a point? That was kind of what I was asking about, it seems to me that the velocity field of a fluid naturally lives on the tangent bundle, and this is a thing that is routinely integrated.

Comment: Tangent bundle of an embedded submanifold, so everything's happening in the ambient $\Bbb R^N$.

Comment: mmm you kind of lost me there, perhaps this exceeds my knowledge a bit

Comment: I'm just saying your physics/fluids applications are to submanifolds (perhaps even domains with boundary) of Euclidean space, and all the integral calculus takes place with values in that (fixed) Euclidean space.